# unable to get value from asp.net dropdownlist on page submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am developing a website using asp.net 3.5.i have created a cascading dropdownlist for country,state,and city.I am filling the state and city using jquery and web service.

But on page submit i am not able to get the selected value of state and city.it is returning blank.

on page load i am using this.

```
ListItem stateitem = new ListItem();
stateitem.Text = "Select";
stateitem.Value = "0";
dd_State.Items.Insert(0,stateitem);
```

I am using jquery and webservice to bind the state and city based on state.

on save button event i am getting the value as.

```
obj.StateId = Convert.ToInt32(dd_State.SelectedItem.Value);

onj.CityId = Convert.ToInt32(dd_City.SelectedItem.Value);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Thanks for letting us know! If you need help, you'll have to ask a question and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: come on, i know you can do better than that, show us a question

Comment: Include some code that shows how you're binding the dropdowns, and how you're retrieving the selected values.

Comment: This was one of those posts I think where the 'question' was in the form of the title: *unable to get value from asp.net dropdownlist on page submit*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding the values client-side, the page won't know about those values because they were not generated from code-behind. This means that on each postback the dropdown will be restored from viewstate as empty so it has no item to mark as selected.
You have at least two options:

1. Lookup the selected value in the Form variables (the selected value is however sent to the server as a common POST behaviour)
2. Use a hidden field in which you store the selected value via script in the onchange event of the dropdown