# How to access the values of a dropdownlist bound using jquery from server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created a cascading dropdownlist using jquery and a webservice in my asp.net website. I have changed the **EnableEventValidation="false"**. I am not getting the selected value which i am binding using jquery on save event.

This is the code I am using to select the value.

```
int stateid = Convert.ToInt32(ddState.SelectedItem.Value);
```

neither I am getting `ddState.SelectedValue`. Both are returning blank.

Comment: I think we need more code. This snipet is not enough.

Comment: At least try to provide correct syntax...

Comment: You need to post the code that shows how the DropDownList is being bound to the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to get value from asp.net dropdownlist on page submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755181/unable-to-get-value-from-asp-net-dropdownlist-on-page-submit)

Comment: You got a perfectly workable answer to your last question.  Please don't ask nearly the same question twice hoping for different answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're manipulating the select list on the client with jQuery it's going to throw off your viewstate, ASP.NET won't be able to track it so that's why you're seeing the behavior of the blank value being returned.

The easiest way around this is just to look at Request.Form(ddState.id) (or Request.Querystring if you're GETing, which you shouldn't be). Then grab out the value from there.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to relaize this the hard way. I was trying to get away from using `UpdatePanels` and rely on client side scripting to handle populating things. Problem is, web forms are so tied into ViewState that those control values don't exist even server side later and it's a real mess. Back to `UpdatePanels` I think...